# Forcing hover actions for touch-screen devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch

I'm using the [jquery-lightbox slider](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) for my website. My website is optimized for mobile devices. The problem is that the 'previous' and 'next' buttons on the slideshow are only shown when you hover over them...Now on devices that are touch screen, this is a problem. How can i force the next and previous buttons to be shown by a hover action?

Here is the code that governs the hover action, but don't know if this is necessary. I believe it can be defined in the initiating front-end code:

```
$(function() {
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
}); /*the initiating code*/
```

The jquery-lightbox js file hover effect code

```
function _set_navigation() {
            $('#lightbox-nav').show();

            // Instead to define this configuration in CSS file, we define here. And it´s need to IE. Just.
            $('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev,#lightbox-nav-btnNext').css({ 'background' : 'transparent url(' + settings.imageBlank + ') no-repeat' });

            // Show the prev button, if not the first image in set
            if ( settings.activeImage != 0 ) {
                if ( settings.fixedNavigation ) {
                    $('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev').css({ 'background' : 'url(' + settings.imageBtnPrev + ') left 15% no-repeat' })
                        .unbind()
                        .bind('click',function() {
                            settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage - 1;
                            _set_image_to_view();
                            return false;
                        });
                } else {
                    // Show the images button for Next buttons
                    $('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev').unbind().hover(function() {
                        $(this).css({ 'background' : 'url(' + settings.imageBtnPrev + ') left 15% no-repeat' });
                    },function() {
                        $(this).css({ 'background' : 'transparent url(' + settings.imageBlank + ') no-repeat' });
                    }).show().bind('click',function() {
                        settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage - 1;
                        _set_image_to_view();
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }

            // Show the next button, if not the last image in set
            if ( settings.activeImage != ( settings.imageArray.length -1 ) ) {
                if ( settings.fixedNavigation ) {
                    $('#lightbox-nav-btnNext').css({ 'background' : 'url(' + settings.imageBtnNext + ') right 15% no-repeat' })
                        .unbind()
                        .bind('click',function() {
                            settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage + 1;
                            _set_image_to_view();
                            return false;
                        });
                } else {
                    // Show the images button for Next buttons
                    $('#lightbox-nav-btnNext').unbind().hover(function() {
                        $(this).css({ 'background' : 'url(' + settings.imageBtnNext + ') right 15% no-repeat' });
                    },function() {
                        $(this).css({ 'background' : 'transparent url(' + settings.imageBlank + ') no-repeat' });
                    }).show().bind('click',function() {
                        settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage + 1;
                        _set_image_to_view();
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
            // Enable keyboard navigation
            _enable_keyboard_navigation();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the option `fixedNavigation:true` to your initialization code, this will keep the Next and Prev buttons available all the time

```
$('#gallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
```

Comment: no ways, that easy...can't believe it...did not pick that up. Thank you very much!